# JavaScript: Programmatically capture frame of YouTube video

Tags: javascript, flash

Can I programmatically capture frames of a Flash video inside Chrome?

I ask because I can corrupt YouTube video frames with pixels outside the browser (using WebGL) and I want to extract those corrupted frames programmatically (e.g. using JavaScript).

Of course, I would then report the vulnerability to Google (and potentially earn a vulnerability cash prize).